# No logo in app navigation bar - can this work?

Tags: usability, navigation, mobile-application, logos

Recently I have reviewed some reputed apps (Facebook, Glassdoor, LinkedIn, Freecharge). They have removed their logo from their navigation bar. Is this a recent design trend?

[image]

I am also working on an app and am also planning to remove the logo from the navigation bar. Can this work? IS there any logic behind this, or a rule, relating to this? Could you please suggest?

Comment: You say 'can this work' - What do you mean by 'work' here? The application will clearly still function, so what is your actual concern about not displaying a logo? How will you define your application as 'working' if it does / doesn't have a logo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brand awareness is the most powerful aspect of marketing. As you can notice, these applications remain recognizable despite the logo has been removed from the header. People are so used to using this apps that they simply know what is what.

In case of this applications removing logo is also a great way of creating extra space that can be used (like that camera button in facebook app).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Ivan Venediktov.

Also, the logo is usually used as a 'home button' in apps and websites. In these cases, the app already has a dedicated home button therefore having the logo present would be purely for aesthetics yet as Ivan says, these companies are so recognisable there is no need for the logo.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to tell what is the 'trend' because different applications tend to have their own specific requirements both in terms of technical constraints and user preferences.

In fact I think if you look at more examples you will find that the no logo in app navigation bar is not necessarily a trend, but a pattern that has been adopted and discarded as different products go through design changes and iterations over the years.

I think in the example with the LinkedIn app there is probably so much they need to fit on the menu that they didn't want to take up more space with the logo, and you have also shown android app examples so it would be interesting to see the comparison with iOS apps.